# How to find minimum of summation of all column elements in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

How can I calculate the minimum of summation of all columns in a dataframe?

```
Row a  Col1 Col2 Col3
Row b   1    2    3
Row c   2    3    4
Row d   3    4    5
```

For `Col1`: `1 + 2 + 3 = 6`; `Col2`: `9`; `Col3`: `12`

Since the sum of `Col1` is the lowest, `Col1` should be printed.

Answer (score 0):

Use `sum()` to compute the sum of each column, and then `idxmin()` to return the name of the column with the lowest sum:

```
>>> df.sum().idxmin()
'Col1'
```